Superscript, multi line in ggplot label -- Unicode issue
The answer from this post addresses a spacing issue for ggplots with multi lines and exponents in the second line. Specifically something like this:
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = expression(paste('This is the first line of the x label\n', x^-1, ')')))

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the superscript minus from unicode working. I tried all of these options. Here is an example that gets a minus sign but not a superscript minus sign:
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = 'This is the first line of the x label\n(x\U2212\u00b9)')

Trying other unicode values yields a box in Rstudio like this (trying out \u207B):

Any help is appreciated!

Maybe use \u207B (and not \u2212) i.e. ⁻ (U+207B,  Superscript Minus) instead of − (U+2212,  Minus Sign)?

I had tried that and got a strange box, I've now edited to question to include that! Thanks!

Here are two options to achieve your desired result. The first ones uses atop and the second uses ggtext and an HTML <sup> tag:
library(ggplot2)

iris |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = expression(
    atop(
      "This is the first line of the x label",
      (x^{"\u2212" * 1})
    )
  ))



library(ggtext)

iris |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "This is the first line of the x label<br>(x<sup>\u22121</sup>)") +
  theme(
    axis.title = ggtext::element_markdown()
  )


